# QMediaPlayer play no sound when winmm.dll in my program

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer, winmm

i have used QMediaPlayer to play some sound,it worked well.
then i used some third device and it`s dll api depends on the windows winmm.dll,
and then my QMediaPlayer played no sound when i join the winmm.dll to my program.
i dont know why.
i thought the winmm.dll have influenced the QMediaPlayer.